# Нужна ли запятая после после ООО "Ромашка"?

Tags: пунктуация

```
ООО "Ромашка" в ответ на Ваш запрос от 02.02.2017 г. №108 направляет Вам 
отчетную информацию в рамках исполнения мероприятий, предусмотренных 
Распоряжением от 12.10.11 №16
```

Comment: В тексте нет 1980. О какой запятой речь?

Comment: о запятой после ООО "Ромашка" и перед "направляет"

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу: после знака "№" следует ставить пробел; после даты, оформленной таким образом - 02.02.2017, "г." не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо, я исправил мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Текст плохо составлен. Пример исправления:

**В ответ на Ваш запрос № 108 от 02.02.2017 ООО "Ромашка" направляет Вам 
отчетную информацию в рамках исполнения мероприятий, предусмотренных 
Распоряжением № 16 от 12.10.2011.**

(1) Последовательность слов: в ответ на Ваш запрос....ООО "Ромашка" направляет Вам информацию.
(2) Последовательность слов: запрос №.... от .....
(3) Единообразие в изображении лет: 2017, 2011
(4) Получилось: "информация в рамках исполнения мероприятий"(?!). Возможно, имелось в виду "направляет в рамках исполнения мероприятий"?

Comment: Спасибо огромное